# Can I build an Event based on a Behavior change in reactive-banana?

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, frp, reactive-banana

The goal here is to build an Event that triggers whenever a Behavior changes under some observation.

To make it a bit more concrete, let's say I have:

- a `bFoo :: Behavior a`, which I like to think it as a time-varied state.
- a function `diffA :: a -> a -> Maybe b` to tell whether certain part of value of `bFoo` has been changed (together with a bit more info indicating what has changed, or leaving me some room for avoiding boolean blindness)

and now I want to build an Event `eChanged :: Event b` that triggers if and only if we have a `Just _` coming out from `diffA fooBefore fooAfter`.

Here comes the problem: it seems the framework only allows you to look at one Behavior value at the `Moment`. So I don't have access two values to compare against each other. I've been looking at [Reactive.Banana.Combinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-1.2.1.0/docs/Reactive-Banana-Combinators.html) but still doesn't have much idea about whether it's possible.

Few more bits and pieces in case those are helpful or spark any new ideas:

### Event-based rather than Behavior-based?

The first thing I can think of is simply to allow myself to have access to more details:
`bFoo` is `accumB`-ed from an Event `eUpdate`, but `eUpdate` doesn't necessarily update anything. So yes, we do have access to `eFoo :: Event a` if we want to, but I want to avoid using it as I think it as an implementation detail of `bFoo`.

### A Failed Attempt

My current attempt looks like:

```hs
networkDesc :: MomemtIO ()
networkDesc = do
  ...
  foo <- valueB bFoo
  let eChanged = filterJust $ fmap (diffA foo) eUpdate
  ...
```

This doesn't work as `foo` is not changed over time.

## Last resort

My last resort is to `reactimate` on `eFoo`, do the comparison outside of the framework and feed result back into the network - sounds doable but that defeats the purpose of having this network to take care of all the logic.

Comment: You need to keep an `Event` around. It's not an implemention detail; it's an essential driver of the network. That `Event` can be the underlying one, or it can carry difference values, etc., or it can even just be a `()` tick, but I think it's pretty essential that you have it. `reflex` bundles up these kinds of things nicely as `Dynamic` and `Incremental`; you may have to do it manually for `reactive-banana`.